# Display heading and Content in Single Line

Tags: css, html, web

I want to display Heading and its content in a single line but it splits into two lines.

For example:

```
<h3> Some Heading: </h3>
<p> Some Content </p>
```

In this I want to display it like:

```
Some Heading: Some Content
```

If anyone can help solve this, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your css codes.

```
h3,p {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I would probably add some vertical-align, there. As not every browser defaults the same

Answer (score 1):

Already answered by @Dogukan Cavus.

The Heading and Content can be displayed in Single line by adding display: inline-block to css style.

```
<h3 style="display: inline-block"> Some Heading: </h3>
<p style="display: inline-block"> Some Content </p>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a4aME/1/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both your tags by a `div` and set the `div`s **display** property to **flex**.

```
<div style="display: flex">
   <h3> Some Heading: </h3>
   <p> Some Content </p>
</div>
```